# How to verify that a user is logged in to a site from another site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a site based on asp.net mvc on windows hosting. Now I need one more site based on php linux. I authonticate a user on windows site and let him upload some information. Now I want this information to go to linux based site. This information could be audio/video or images. 
How would i make sure that he can only load to linux server when he is logged into windows based site.

So basically I am thinking before the linux based save something, it should verify that the user is logged into the windows site. What about the logout process.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: share a database between them containing session information?

Comment: Implementing/resorting to a single sign on solution would be advisable, other solutions are using some kind of time token (created on win machine and controlled on linux site).

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these two services use the same domain, your windows site can save some value in the cookie, and the linux site will identify whether user is authenticated base on these values. However it will only work if the two services are under same domain name (can be different port).

If not, I think Single-Sign On is advisable for security reasons, and OpenID or OAuth is recommended.